# How to replace numbers with same 'stem' that occur in two files using same logic?

Tags: java, c

So basically I have two .txt files that have the same numbers (16 digits), with the first 8 digits all being identical (eg. 12345678) and then the next 8 digits being random (eg. 38462943). What I have been trying to do is replace the numbers in both files to any unique random 16 digit numbers, using the same logic in both files.

TL;DR - The problem I'm having is how can I locate the same numbers in each file and then replace them using the same logic?

**note - the files do not just contain the numbers I want randomized, there is other information on the same line (eg.line 1 1234, 1234567800000234, 5678)

**example:** (notice how numbers are same but are not in same order)

*File 1*
1234567800000234
1234567800011523
1234567800284828

*File 2*
1234567800284828
1234567800011523
1234567800000234

**expected output**  (just want numbers randomized, doesn't matter if stem is changed or not)

*File 1*
9348384028472894
9350148852541329
9761213142823690

*File 2*
9761213142823690
9350148852541329
9348384028472894

**edit - clairification

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Please provide your code, we can't help you if we don't see what you have implemented so far.

Comment: @Mureinik First, I tried simply using the text edit find and replace tool, however, this has two problems. 1. It can't be used for multiple files at once. 2. I would have to manually enter the random numbers (too time consuming as file contains 120,000 rows of numbers).

Comment: `str.replaceAll("12345678\\d{8}", String.format("%08d", random.nextInt(System.nanoTime())))` ?

Comment: You have not described the problem adequately: (1) You say you “just want numbers randomized, can keep same stem” but your examples do not seem to show a stem being kept—what stem has 9348384028472894 kept from 1234567800000234? (2) You say you want the numbers random but the same in both files. The only way ensure random numbers are the same in two files is to select, for each number, a replacement randomly once and then use it in both files. This requires that you process the files together or keep a map from original numbers to replacement numbers, so you can reuse the map.…

Comment: @leopal I'm fairly new to coding, so far I have implemented a simple file I/O code in C.

Comment: @VictorGubin the problem is that there is other information before and after those numbers that are not relevant. each number however is on its own line

Comment: … (3) You say you want “random” numbers but say you want the same “logic” in both files. Random numbers are born of randomness, not logic. Saying you want logic suggests what you actually want is a deterministic hash function, possibly a 1-1 map from 16-digit numbers to 16-digit numbers, that conceals the original values while being reproducible. In this case, you should describe the purposes more, as a proper solution may require cryptographically strong functions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the reply. 1) My point was that it really does not matter if the stem is kept or not, I just want any random 16 digit number. 2) Exactly! How would I be able to process both files at once and replace the numbers? This is the problem I'm having. 3) By same logic I just meant that each number in both files is replaced by the same random number (eg. if 1234 appears in both files, it would be replaced to 3948 in both files)

Comment: Replacing each number with itself satisfies the constraints as far as i can tell. Until we know what the purpose of trying to change the number is, we have no reason to change it nor any criterion for what sort of alternative should be used. If you merely wish to change the numbers, then simply read each line and replace the number with the number that results from incrementing every digit, wrapping from 9 to 0. Thus 1234567800000234 would become 2345678911111345, and the same changes would be made in both files.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Even that would be perfect, however manually doing this to both files would not be practical as there are ~100k lines in each file.

Comment: Problem solving is a large part of being a computer programmer and doesn't involve computers. Start by breaking the problem into smaller pieces. Write the steps you need to take to solve each of these smaller pieces. Only after you have a clear understanding of a solution should you worry about writing code. Be sure to pick a single language and then translate the description of your solution into code.

Comment: What that said, one possible solution is to just replace the numbers in one file at a time. In the first file, keep a dictionary or map which stores the original number as the key and the new number as the value. For all other files, just use lookup the new value from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have two real options here.

1. Use a pseudorandom conversion on the numbers that meet the criteria -- run it through a SHA1 or something.  This will produce the same output every time, so you don't have to keep track.  It won't be truly random though.
2. Keep a list of every substitution you've made, so that when you go through the second file you can use that list to find out what the correct substitution should be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to do the pseudorandom conversion automatically? For example turn all the 1s into 5s and the 5s into 7s etc...